# Using onBeforeUnload screws up the browsers History in Angular

Tags: angular, onbeforeunload, angular-router, angular-router-guards

When the user is done entering data on a page, I want them to go back to the previous page (ex.  Main Page -> Input Page).  If I redirect them when they click submit, I will end up with a circular history (Main Page -> Input Page -> Main Page).  Hence, when the user clicks submit I call `window.history.back()`.

To prevent loss of data, I listen for the beforeUnload event. If the user has not submitted the form, I prompt to ensure they know they are going to lose their changes.

The problem I am having is that if the user tries to go back without submitting their data, click cancel to stay on the page, and then click submit.  The 1st time they hit back is cancelled and then after submit I execute a history.back(), but that ends up going back 2 entries in the history instead of 1.  It's almost as if when I cancel the back event that the previous URL (Main Page) is being dropped from the history stack all together.  Hence, hitting submit goes past that page and back to a New Tab page.

I know stack management is crazy difficult, but can't figure out how to go to the previous URL if the user cancels the onBeforeUnload to stay on the page and the hits submit.  Seems if the user cancels it, when I call history.back() it should go back to the Main page.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue was related to Angular, which I neglected to mention in the question.  It appears the [Angular navigation gets screwed up when a CanDeactivate guard cancels a navigation](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13586).  There is a proposed work around that appears to be working for me.